# Is is possible to reverse params to original http request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I print the **params** in my controller

How to convert to original http request, like

`http://SERVER/queries?product_type="IF"..`

```
{
            "market" => "cffex_hfts",
      "product_type" => "IF",
         "frequency" => "minute",
    "contract_month" => "2014-03-01 00:00:00",
          "start_at" => "2014-01-10 01:26:00",
            "end_at" => "2014-01-10 08:26:00",
        "controller" => "queries",
            "action" => "index"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
params = {
        "market" => "cffex_hfts",
  "product_type" => "IF",
     "frequency" => "minute",
"contract_month" => "2014-03-01 00:00:00",
      "start_at" => "2014-01-10 01:26:00",
        "end_at" => "2014-01-10 08:26:00",
    "controller" => "queries",
        "action" => "index"
}

params.to_query
=> "action=index&contract_month=2014-03-01+00%3A00%3A00&controller=queries&end_at=2014-01-10+08%3A26%3A00&frequency=minute&market=cffex_hfts&product_type=IF&start_at=2014-01-10+01%3A26%3A00"
```

Reference: http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/to_query

Comment: Excuse me how to convert `2014-03-01+00%3A00%3A00` in plain text?